# In-memory xml to xsd translator?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a requirement to generate a schema from an XML document. The wrinkle is that the XML document will be available as one big String of content, and the XSD must remain in-memory.

The XSD will initially be sorted by tags and attributes and hashed to generate a "fingerprint" of a visited xml document. Therefore the data structure for the resulting XSD does not matter, as long as it's an in-memory structure of some kind.

I cannot create intermediate files, nor can I do an "exec" to the shell to accomplish this.

I am aware of, and have played around with, several command-line tools to generate a schema from an XML file. I have opened up a couple of these and was disappointed that all the tools I have looked at make the assumption that the source and destination are files and this assumption permeates the code such that I can't just replace the driver class with my own to reformat input and output.

Does anyone know of a translator package that will be able to handle this task?

Comment: Why XSD in particular? Can't you just transform the XML directly to some kind of fingerprint (e.g. XSLT to remove the actual element content)?

Comment: The goal is to recognized different xml documents that share a schema when an explicit schema is lacking. This approach is not perfect - xml documents that contain or lack optional elements for example would have different schemas - but it's a starting point. The kind of processing on the xml document that is being done is expensive and this will permit the solution to hash into persistent results from already-visited xml files.